# Dynamic library option with multi entry points

Tags: webpack

I find an example of webpack [library option with multiple entry points and UMD](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-part-library)

Here is the **webpack.config.js** in the example:

```
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        alpha: "./alpha",
        beta: "./beta"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "js"),
        filename: "MyLibrary.[name].js",
        library: ["MyLibrary", "[name]"],
        libraryTarget: "umd"
    }
}
```

My question is how to config `filename` & `library` dynamically. What I want is:

- `filename` for entry `alpha` to be `a.js`
- `filename` for entry `beta` to be `b.js`
- `library` for entry `alpha` to be `Alpha`
- `library` for entry `beta` to be `Beta`.

So I wonder if I can config these options through a `function` like this:

```
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        alpha: "./alpha",
        beta: "./beta"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "js"),
        filename: function(entryKey, entryValue) {
            if (entryKey === 'alpha') return 'a.js';
            if (entryKey === 'beta') return 'b.js';
        },
        library: function(entryKey, entryValue) {
            if (entryKey === 'alpha') return 'Alpha';
            if (entryKey === 'beta') return 'Beta';
        },
        libraryTarget: "umd"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

From webpack 3.1.0, you can export multi configurations from webpack.config.js

So you can try the following:

```
  module.exports = [
    {
      entry: "./alpha",
      output: {
          path: path.join(__dirname, "js"),
          filename: "a.js",
          library: "Alpha",
          libraryTarget: "umd"
      }
    },
    {
      entry: "./beta",
      output: {
          path: path.join(__dirname, "js"),
          filename: "b.js",
          library: "Beta",
          libraryTarget: "umd"
      }
    },

]
```

Related docs: [Exporting multiple configurations](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations)

Answer (score 6):

You could set the name like so

```
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        Alpha: "./alpha",
        Beta: "./beta"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "js"),
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]',
        libraryTarget: "umd"
    }
}
```